# how to test if redshift connection is successful in R shiny app?

Tags: shiny, amazon-redshift

I'm developing a R shiny app that can pull data from Redshift based on user inputs. I wanted to test if the Redshift connection was successful before proceeding. Is there an existing R function to test if the connection is successful?
We can see the connection in R console while in shiny app I wanted to test it and provide feedback to users. Is it possible to write some codes like following in Shinyserver

```
      con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                            Driver =driver,
                            Server= server,
                            Port = 5439,
                            Database = database,
                            UID = uid,
                            PWD = pwd,
                            sslmode = "allow")
  
  # Ideally, a line of code like this line of mock codes to return error message
       if (connectionSuccess = TRUE) {
            stop("Please check your credentials!")
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check the `dbIsValid` function: https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbisvalid

Answer (score 0):

I think a workaround, with the same end effect, might be using [dbi::dbCanConnect](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbCanConnect.html) to check if the connection is possible, if so, then you try to connect to the host. You would end up with something similar to:

```r
## Test if the connection is possible and if it authenticates successfully.
connection_check <- dbCanConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                            Driver =driver,
                            Server= server,
                            Port = 5439,
                            Database = database,
                            UID = uid,
                            PWD = pwd,
                            sslmode = "allow")


if(connection_check) {
   ## If it does authenticate...
   con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                            Driver =driver,
                            Server= server,
                            Port = 5439,
                            Database = database,
                            UID = uid,
                            PWD = pwd,
                            sslmode = "allow")
} else {
   ## If it fails...
   stop("Please check your credentials!")
}
```